# Environment Error [Errno 2] while installing pip packages or upgrading pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, cryptography

pip used to work fine until recently. First I was trying to install a pip-package using

```
pip install -e [some-git-link]
```

and I get the error

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'

I then cd'ed into site-packages and the folder is empty. Indeed, I have pip installed in dis-packages and its version is 18.1, not 19.0!

I tried to update pip through

```
pip install -U pip
```

but I get the same error.

Typing

```
pip --version
```

I get

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/**init**.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
>     warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)
>
> pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

so it seems that pip 18.1 is installed. Indeed, if I try

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

I get

> python-pip is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4).
>
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.

I was wondering if all these problems were coming from the warning on the cryptography, and so I tried to do

```
sudo pip install --upgrade cryptography
```

but obviously I go back to the same Environment Error.

Comment: I've solved it only by deleting pip folders in local and then re-install it. I know that this is not the proper way of uninstalling pip, but I was not making it through `pip uninstall pip`

Answer (score 4):

Thou shalt not use `sudo` with `pip`. Using `sudo` with `pip` is asking for trouble. When you do that you are having `pip` and your OS's package manager get into a fight. When they fight no one wins, least of all your Python installation and personal sanity. I know countless tutorials tell you to `sudo pip install`, but they are not your friends. The only safe and reliable way to maintain a functional Python installation is to let your OS's package manager manage what it wants to manage and either use `pip install --user` or virtual environments (using either `virtualenv` or optionally `python -m venv` if you're on Python 3).

I really can't stress enough that you will **constantly** be running into little weird things (and occasional catastrophic problems) within your Python installation if you persistently sudo install things. Learn to love virtual environments! You can even modify your shell's `PATH` so that things you install in an environment are available as commands (which is commonly why people think they need `sudo pip install`).

Answer (score 0):

You could test to update PythonOpenSSL :

$ sudo python -m easy_install --upgrade pyOpenSSL

If not Ok, please do :

$ sudo pip install --upgrade cryptography

But error with : $ sudo pip

So do after :

$ sudo python -m easy_install --upgrade pyOpenSSL

Have Fun,

Johan MRe

Answer (score 0):

How to deal with "Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError" when upgrade pip

First run command line in Administration mode both window and OS:

Next,

For windows: use this command to upgrade pip

```
python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

For MacOS:

```
sudo python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error trying to install packages while building a Docker image (with python:3.8 as base). Upgrading pyOpenSSL as @Johan MRe suggested solved it for me.

```
RUN python3 -m easy_install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
```